# vue.js v-model bind to subproperty of json object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a JSON object called `valuesRequired` which is a listing of all values that I am diffing against for other purposes. What I would like to do is use this already created object to bind to the inputs. I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Here is the code, I've only provided the necessary aspects to show what I desire to do and not all of the other methods etc. The aspect I want to do is specifically `v-model="valuesRequired.{{item.name}}"` which in the below example would end up being `v-model="valuesRequired.foo"`

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in listItems" :key="item.description">
        <label :for="item.name">{{ item.description }}</label>
        <input :type="item.type" :name="item.name" v-model="valuesRequired.{{item.name}}" />
    </li>
</ul>
</fieldset>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                valuesRequired: {
                    foo: "bar"
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Currently to work around this I'm dynamically adding properties to `this.$data` but that then requires me to map them into the `valuesRequired` object.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: `{{item.name}}` doesn't do anything, it's already reading everything in `v-model` as code so you should be writing `v-model='valuesRequired[item.name]'`

Comment: @chbchb55 It's hard to know at times where the vuejs magic stops, that worked out perfectly. Mind making it the answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: That's not Vue magic; it's plain javascript.

Comment: I posted it as the answer

Comment: @Bert LOL, I'm aware that that is JavaScript - what I meant is I wasn't aware of what is/isn't allowed within the vue templates. I already had the vue linter yelling at me with various other things that I had tried, such as the utilization of the handlebar approach to dynamic access to the valuesRequired object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `{{item.name}}` is used when the default is text

Your issue is that when you do `v-model='valuesRequired.{{item.name}}'` this is being rendered as `v-model='valuesRequired.{{My Name}}'`.

Essentially, the text you pass to `v-model` is evaluated as JavaScript, therefore, you should use bracket notation to access `valuesRequired` at `item.name`.

[What you want is the following (JSFiddle Link):](https://jsfiddle.net/chbchb55/eywraw8t/142062/)

**Vue.js Script Setup:**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    item: {
      name: 'foo'
    },
    valuesRequired: {
      foo: 'bar',
      baz: 'faz'
    }
  }
})
```

**Vue.js HTML Template:**

```
<div id="app">
  <input type='text' v-model='valuesRequired[item.name]' />
  <p>
    {{valuesRequired}}
  </p>
</div>
```